# Deleting QObject during signal/slot processing

Tags: c++, qt

I know that deleting a QObject from a slot processing could crash the app because it could have other queued events. 
So, instead of use "delete obj" i will use obj->deleteLater(). As far as I know the obj waits to process all queued events and then "delete obj".

> **QObject::~QObject ()**
>   All signals to and from the object are automatically disconnected, and any pending posted events for the object are removed from the event queue. However, it is often safer to use deleteLater() rather than deleting a QObject subclass directly.

But, what's about other signal/slot processes? I mean, if you have connected signals/slot from objects which live in different threads as Qt::QueuedConnection or Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection. Are they dequeued to be processed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deleteLater` will remove object from thread which object belongs to. `Qt::QueuedConnection` and `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` (also `Qt::AutoConnection`) are work in this way that slot is invoked from event loop of thread which object with slot belongs to.
So if you add to this quote you posted this means that any pending `Qt::*QueuedConnection` will be automatically dismissed when object gets destroyed. This means that you are safe when using those connections and `deleteLater`. Problem may appear when you will use `Qt::DirectConnection` with different thread, or when you try to destroy object directly (`delete pointer;`) from wrong thread.

Comment: Are those the only requirements that allow you to say `delete obj;` rather than `obj->deleteLater();`? both inter-thread `Qt::DirectConnection`s and deletion are things you should never do anway, so what does "it is often safer" mean. What king of guarantees QT gives us and under what circumstances?

Comment: problem can  appear only when there is multithreading issue. If all methods are called from proper thread everything should work out of the box. There is one exception: dangling pointers (but this applies to all C++/C frameworks and should be always avoided). If some methods are precessed in different thread, then during destruction you should make sure that this task has completed. Ask less general question if you need more details.

Comment: My question was: what of internal qt's workings might require you to use `deleteLater` rather than `delete`? I know of all usual multi-threading issues, and that necessity to synchronize access also require synchronizing destruction. But I cannot use synchronization primitives with i.e. signal/slot mechanics, can I? Btw, calling different methods from different threads on the same object can still fail even if you use `deleteLater` to delete it, so this is out of scope here.

Comment: I can't recall exact example when this is most useful but, the main advantage of `deleteLater` is that it is a slot. Second thing is `deleteLater` is invoked when current event loop gains control, not when new event loop gain control - its is useful when you have a modal window. Of course there are cases when regular `delete` is better, for example long running loop which do lots of allocations and deallocations then memory footprint will be more compact.

Answer (score 0):

As per Qt Documents

> The object will be deleted when control returns to the event loop. If
>   the event loop is not running when this function is called (e.g.
>   `deleteLater()` is called on an object before `QCoreApplication::exec()`),
>   the object will be deleted once the event loop is started. **If
>   `deleteLater()` is called after the main event loop has stopped, the
>   object will not be deleted**. Since Qt 4.8, if `deleteLater()` is called
>   on an object that lives in a thread with no running event loop, the
>   object will be destroyed when the thread finishes.
>
> Note that entering and leaving a new event loop (e.g., by opening a
>   modal dialog) will not perform the deferred deletion; for the object
>   to be deleted, the control must return to the event loop from which
>   `deleteLater()` was called.
>
> Note: It is safe to call this function more than once; when the first
>   deferred deletion event is delivered, any pending events for the
>   object are removed from the event queue.

In `Qt::QueuedConnection` type `deleteLater()` will wait to finish thread.but In `Qt::DirectConnection` when anyone delete object directly, it may crash the application.
In that case you need to check thread is running or not before deleting.