# In QT is it safe to emit a signal from a closeEvent function?

Tags: c++, qt

Please, consider the following code

```
class A : public QWidget
{
    signals:
       void readyToBeClosed();
    protected:
       void closeEvent(QCloseEvent* e)
       {
           QWidget::closeEvent(e);
           emit readyToBeClosed();
       }
}

class B: public QWidget
{
public:
   B(A* obj)
   {
       connect(obj,SIGNAL(readyToBeCLosed()),this,SLOT(cleanUp());
   }

private slots:
   void cleanUp()
   {
        //DO SOMETHING
   }
}
```

Is it safe? May I risk to crash cause the object obj is destroyed after the emit signal and before the cleanUp function returned?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you going to use `obj` in the `cleanUp()` function? Btw, closing a widget does not mean it will be destroyed, unless you set `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute.

Comment: This could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505544/deleting-qobject-during-signal-slot-processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, because the signal/slot system works like function calls (with the addition of the "connection" mechanism), as specified in [the Qt Documentation about Signals and Slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html).

When you emit a signal, all slots connected to it are called, and once they've all returned, control returns to the code that emitted the signal. So, the next line of code in your `closeEvent` function, just after the signal, will execute after all slots connected to this signal have returned.

Thus, in your case, the A object will still be there and valid. Note that closing a widget doesn't necessarily delete it (as noted by vahancho in the comments).

**EDIT**: **In fact, it depends if you manipulate A through a pointer in `cleanup`**. If `B` doesn't store a pointer to `A`, it will be fine no matter what (because the signal will be emitted anyway, the slot will be called, and if `A` isn't accessed inside the slot, there'll be no problem at all, *whatever the connection type that has been specified or assumed*). If `cleanup` somehow accesses `A` through a pointer, then read the following:

As pointed out, I should indeed have precised that this is the case only if you're using  a `Qt::DirectConnection` mode for this connection. Indeed, this mode yields the behavior I described, and is assumed (the default parameter for the `connect` function is `Qt::AutoConnection`, which automatically choose based on the context, i.e. signal from a thread to a slot that'd run in another thread)

If you use `Qt::QueuedConnection` or that the `Qt::AutoConnection` assumes it, then you could indeed have undefined behavior because the call to the slot will be queued to the receiver thread and will only execute once control returns to this thread's event loop. If this happens after `A` has been actually destroyed,

Comment: That is not entirely true, it depends on [how the connection is made](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum). If you don't specify anything, it is determined automatically. Qt signals can work across threads by queuing up the signal calls and that is hardly the same as a normal function call.

Comment: If no queued connection is directly specified - then in original question all will be OK, because both classes are children of QWidget and they can exist only in (same) GUI thread.

Comment: @fish In fact it depends if `A` is actually accessed in `cleanup`. If this is not the case, then even a `Qt::QueuedConnection` will be fine, as A can be gone at the moment the slot is called _if the slot itself doesn't somehow access `A` through a pointer_. I've edited my post to take both cases into account.

Comment: @JBL yes, I meant my comment as additional information, not to say your answer was incorrect; just that it didn't cover the general case, but sounded like it did.